# Issue in converting encrypted HLS with FFMPEG to UDP

Tags: ffmpeg, encryption, vlc-media-player, udp, hls

We are looking for help in debugging a problem related to converting encrypted HLS to UDP output.
If we download encrypted HLS content and then convert it to UDP, it works well. But if we directly convert encrypted HLS to UDP eg,

ffmpeg -re -i $1 -c copy -f mpegts "udp://238.5.6.35:7409?pkt_size=1316&localaddr=192.168.0.35" -v debug

with the above command,there are timing issues with the UDP output. When we analyzed the UDP output, errors are related to PCR, length between sections are too long for different tables.

We tried to fix with adding buffers like -max_delay 5000000, but did not work. VLC works well with encrypted HLS.
Any clue will help us.

Comment: Thank you so much! Errors have reduced alot by using  : ffmpeg -re -i $1  -c copy -flush_packets 0  -f mpegts -pcr_period 20 -muxrate 5550k "udp://238.5.6.35:7408?pkt_size=1316&&bitrate=5550000&localaddr=192.168.0.35" -v debug We had to add bitrate in UDP output too.

Comment: This is well noted. I've also updated the answer with your recommendation on specifying bitrate in the UDP protocol string. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to ensure that FFmpeg's [mpegts muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#mpegts-1) achieves the following objectives at output:

1. True CBR (Constant Bitrate) output.
2. A fixed payload size not exceeding the MTU size.

To achieve a constant bitrate output, set:

(a). The private muxer option value for mpegts `pcr_period` to 20.

(b). The private muxer option `muxrate` , which must be large enough to compensate for all stream variants in the output inclusive of any muxer overhead(s).

(c). The `bitrate` parameter should be added to the UDP protocol string, and when set, *must* be equal to the `-muxrate` parameter value.

For a fixed payload size, ensure that:

(a). The value set is the nearest multiple of 188 bytes that fits in a standard 1500 MTU size, ie 1316 (188x7) via the UDP prototol private option `pkt_size=1316` as you had above.

(b). The output option `-flush_packets 0` is set [as documented](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2748#comment:19).

Using your example above, a sample command with the changes above would look like this:

```
ffmpeg -re -i $1 -c copy -flush_packets 0 -f mpegts -pcr_period 20 -muxrate 5550k "udp://238.5.6.35:7409?pkt_size=1316&bitrate=5550000&localaddr=192.168.0.35" -v debug
```

Take note of the issued `-muxrate` value and adjust as necessary to ensure it matches the requirements in 1(b), otherwise the output may be invalid, with DTS and PCR errors [encountered on runtime](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4279).

**Hint:** You may also initially retest with the `-muxrate` parameter omitted, all else being constant:

```
ffmpeg -re -i $1 -c copy -flush_packets 0 -f mpegts -pcr_period 20  "udp://238.5.6.35:7409?pkt_size=1316&localaddr=192.168.0.35" -v debug
```

To validate the workflow, adding the `-muxrate` and bitrate values later on using FFmpeg's bitrate hints from the console output as a starting point.